# El repositorio X no tiene fichero de publicacion

Tags: linux, ubuntu, repositorio

soy nuevo en Ubuntu vengo desde windows y me a costado un poco familiarizarme con el sistema, recientemente me interesé por instalar algunos temas para mejorar la apariencia y tal, anduve navegando un poco y encontré varios temas, pero para instalarlos, todos me pedian este comando por ejemplo "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes", el caso es que ni este, ni ningun repositorio me a dado otra cosa que error: El repositorio http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu hirsute Release no tiene un fichero de Publicación, e googleado un montón y no encuentro nada claro, supongo que hay una buena razón, pero no puedo evitar pensar en: ¡Por qué no solo me dan un enlace de descarga y ya?, ni idea, quisás mi pensamiento "windows" me hace pensar que esta gente está obsecionada con la terminal, el error que me da es este: [image: terminal] tengo la versión 21.04

Comment: Puedes poner en enlace de dónde has sacado la información que posteas? Para ver si hay algo que hayas pasado por alto, a mi linux también me parece un dolor en los....

Comment: Bienvenido s SO! Qué comando estás tratando de ejecutar ahí? Y, por favor, coloca el comando y la salida como texto, no como screenshot.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, el comando es: "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes"

Comment: Hola @AQMR Aquí hay algunos https://exdebian.org/foro/error-apt-get-update-el-repositorio-no-tiene-un-fichero-de-publicaci%C3%B3n-activo, https://www.espaciolinux.com/foros/software/solucionado-fallo-con-repositorios-t59651.html, https://foro.vozidea.com/d/273-sudo-apt-update-error-ubuntu-repositorio-no-tiene-un-fichero-de-publicacion

Comment: Y si, es un dolor de cabeza, intento ser receptivo ya que soy nuevo en esto, así que me mantengo pensando "debe haber una buena razón para que sea así" cuando me encuentro con estos problemas, pero no puedo evitar pensar, ¿Cuál es la razón?, No veo porque hacer tan complejo algo que se puede resolver con un par de clicks, pero bueno....."debe haber una buena razón", ....espero